# Accessing similar DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm currently working on a component and I need **access to each `<path>` nodes**. I'm currently storing its attributes in an array and later on I map through it when I render. Let's say there's even 20 or 50 `<path>` elements. I could basically hardcode it and write a ref to each of them but I need a better solution since each of them is unique and I'm planning to **store a single node in a Redux state** for later usage since there are methods I need to use which require path lengths and coordinates.

How do I access each node?

```
    const pathList = [
        { d: 'M 500 500 L 800 500', fill: 'transparent', stroke: '#f00' },
        { d: 'M 810 500 L 1105 500', fill: 'transparent', stroke: '#f00' },
        { d: 'M 1110 500 L 1410 500 L 1410 810 L 810 810', fill: 'transparent', stroke: '#f00' },
        { d: 'M 800 810 L 500 810', fill: 'transparent', stroke: '#f00' },
        { d: 'M 805 495 L 805 195', fill: 'transparent', stroke: '#000' },
        { d: 'M 805 505 L 805 805', fill: 'transparent', stroke: '#000' }
    ];

    const paths = pathList.map(path => <path d={path.d} fill={path.fill} stroke={path.stroke} />);
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: The question is: How do I access each node instead of writing multiple refs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to avoid hard-code refs, you may do something like this

```
const paths = pathList.map((path, index) => {
    this.pathRefs[index] = React.createRef();
    return <path d={path.d} fill={path.fill} stroke={path.stroke} ref={this.pathRefs[index]}/>
});
```